# How to run PhpStorm 9.3 with AdoptOpenJDK

Tags: java, phpstorm

I've replaced Oracle Java with AdoptOpenJDK but unfortunately PhpStorm 9.3 (I know it's old but good enough for me) stopped working well. It runs but it's not opening recent files or windows like terminal etc.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm was written based on Oracle or JetBrains JVM. There's not much you can do to get it working on other JVM/JDKs.

Comment: Are you sure about this? AdoptOpenJDK should be fully compatible with Oracle JDK 8 as i know. (and PhpStorm works well with Oracle JDK 8)

Comment: I switched back to Oracle JDK 8 and the problem persists. I think not related with JVM/JDK directly.

Comment: You're welcome to troubleshoot this with a support team via Help > Contact Support